# Using webpack to import image names from a static folder directory

Tags: webpack, vue.js, require

I currently have a images folder setup in my static directory called "/pictures"

I took the template code from webpacks website but when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

I have attached my code for reference, hopefully someone can help! For context, Im running the code in one of the components of my vue.js app

```
data () {
    return {
        imageDir: "../../static/pictures/",
        images: {}
    }
},
firebase: {
    homePageNotifs : homePageNotifsRef
},

mounted(){
    this.importAll(require.context(this.imageDir, true, /\.png$/))
},

methods: {
    importAll(r) {
        var imgs = {}
        r.keys().forEach(key => (imgs[key] = r(key)))
        this.images = imgs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed a quote from webpack doc site. As per the webpack doc,

> The arguments passed to require.context must be literals!

Hence you can't pass variables as arguments to `require.context`. So the below change should work for you.

```
mounted(){
    this.importAll(require.context("../../static/pictures/", true, /\.png$/))
},
```